# cannot show level 3 subcategory on magento

Tags: magento, categories

i would ask how to make sub-subcategory on magento.

this code only show sub category on level 2, i need to get to level 3.

this is my code

```
<div class="category-products <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('parent_cat_name')->toHtml() ?>">
<?php  echo "<ol class='subcat_list'>"; ?>

 <?php
    $currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');

    if ( $currentCat->getParentId() == Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() )
    {
        // current category is a toplevel category
        $loadCategory = $currentCat;

    }
    else
    {
        // current category is a sub-(or subsub-, etc...)category of a toplevel category
        // load the parent category of the current category
        $loadCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCat->getParentId());
        // @TODO enhance for more nested category levels to display sub-categories
    }    
    $subCategories = explode(',', $loadCategory->getChildren());

    foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId )
    {
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);

        if($cat->getIsActive())
        {       
            <?php  echo "<ol class='subcat_list'>"; ?>                                                      
                echo '<li><a href="'.$cat->getURL().'">'.$cat->getName().'</a>'.'</li>';
            <?php  echo "</ol>"; ?>
        }
    }

?>
<?php  echo "</ol>"; ?>
</div>
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is explained how to Generate Category Tree Recursively
Check this: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-generate-category-tree-recursively

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set category level more that 3 in admin panel.

System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Category Top Navigation -> Maximal Depth

Answer (score 0):

Create the categories as third level means Parent > Child > Sub child after that make sure that you have assigned the 3 lavel depth into the Magento for this navigate to the System > Configuration > Catalog > Category Top Navigation > Maximal Depth.

Use the below code and check

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks